# Compactness & countable dense subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have a question in real analysis!

If $K$ is compact metric space, show that there is a countable dense subset $E$ of $K$

How can i prove it?

Could you help me for the idea or proof?

Comment: I assume you're assuming that $K$ is a metric space? It isn't true otherwise.

Comment: Yes. K is a metric space

Comment: Consider the covers $\mathcal U_n=\left \{ B_{1/n}(x):x\in K \right \}$